# JWT Decode try catch

Tags: php, jwt

I am using JWT for authorization (REST API) in my tiny project. JWT looks to be a very suitable for my project.

Let's say I have this code:

```
$key = "secret";
$token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ"
$data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
```

This code will return an array as on the official page of JWT.

But if I try to run the following codes:

```
$key = "secret";
$token = "abc.abc.abc"
$data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
```

or

```
$key = "secret";
$token = "abc"
$data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
```

PHP will issue an exception/error, how can I handle those exceptions/errors so the end-user will not see them (together with my secret key in the error).

I've tried to do the following:

```
try {
    $key = "secret";
    $token = "abc"
    $data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
} catch (Exception $e) { // Also tried JwtException
    echo 'error';
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I come just to the same issue and the solution to catch this error is:

```
catch (\Exception $e) not catch (Exception $e)
```

so your code become:

```
try {
    $key = "secret";
    $token = "abc"
    $data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));
} catch (\Exception $e) { // Also tried JwtException
    echo 'error';
}
```

found here: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/issues/50