# Is try-catch sufficient to verify JWT?

Tags: php, try-catch, jwt

I am using firebase/php-jwt library to encode and decode JWT and have used try/catch to deal with invalid signatures, expired tokens, and various other exceptions as shown in the code below.

```
try {
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secret_key, array('HS256')); 

    // do something

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), ". Please login again.";  
}
```

What I am wondering is whether using try-catch alone (specifically with firebase/php-jwt library) is sufficient for verifying JWT token? The firebase/php-jwt library is able to handle various exceptions like invalid signatures, expired tokens, etc, so do I need to add some extra code to verify jwt? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Comment: May be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492119/jwt-decode-try-catch?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question

> is sufficient for verifying JWT token?

Yes it is, as long as you use it in the proper way, i.e you provide all the valid parameter needed, which include  the `key`, `token` and write a correct `// do something`.

Example:

```
try {
    $key = "secret";
    $token = "abc"
    $data = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256')); 
} catch (\Exception $e) { // Also tried JwtException
    echo 'error', ". Please login again.";  
}
```